# Kivy Sidebar plus content layout

Tags: python, kivy

I want a fixed width right sidebar on my kivy app with a list of buttons and a main area where to draw things, I am not sure which is the right way to go about it (i.e. which layout), here's where I am at so far:

*layoutApp.py*...

```
from kivy.app import App

class layoutApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    layoutApp().run()
```

And *layoutApp.kv*...

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint_x: 2
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
```

Which produces:

[image]

The issue is that sizes are relative, i.e. the right sidebar width changes depending on screen seize/resize which is not the intended behavior.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of the sidebar, and then have the large button width depend on that by using `ids`:

```
BoxLayout:
    id: top_box
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: top_box.width - bottom_box.width
        BoxLayout:
            id: bottom_box
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 150
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight modifications to @John_Anderson with skinny top aligned buttons:

```
BoxLayout:
    id: top_box
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: top_box.width - bottom_box.width
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 4
            id: bottom_box
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            spacing: 2
            Button:
                id: button_1
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
                text: 'Button 1'
                color: .6, .6, .6, 1
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 192
                height: 40
            Button:
                id: button_2
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
                text: 'Button 2'
                color: .6, .6, .6, 1
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 192
                height: 40
            Button:
                id: button_3
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
                text: 'Button 3'
                color: .6, .6, .6, 1
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 192
                height: 40
            Button:
                id: button_4
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
                text: 'Button 4'
                color: .6, .6, .6, 1
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 192
                height: 40
            Widget:
```

Results in:

[image]